# How to select data from database and display in excel - c#

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I want to select data from database table and display it on excel sheet.

Basically similar to exporting data to excel, but in my case when Ill open the excel, a select query will be fired which will fetch data from table and display in excel sheet from A1 Cell.

Is this possible? I dont need the code by maybe some idea or reference of how to implement it. I am no expert in c#.

Comment: Why you need c# for that: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/tutorial-import-data-into-excel-and-create-a-data-model-4b4e5ab4-60ee-465e-8195-09ebba060bf0

Comment: do you know how to create and or use Macros?

Comment: @MethodMan I want to use c# in addin. I have other features too which i have implemented in c#

Answer (score 0):

there are many ways you can do this, 
it all depends on how you want to manage the logic :
here is a good way to start with :
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/83fe73/solutions-to-export-data-from-database-to-excel-in-C-Sharp/

Comment: mm it actually gets my data in DataGridView. I need it on excel sheet. :\